# Transfer App in iTunes from one account to other

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes

An app was created in Appstore with one developer account named `X`, the app is currently transferred to account named `Y`. From now on `Y` wants to do the app store updations of that app with his own account, But corresponding provisioning profiles of that app are not seen to `Y` in `developer.apple.com`, so `Y` is unable to update the app. Though `Y` can see the App Name and App in his `iTunesConnect.apple.com` account.

What has to be done so that `Y` can see the corresponding certificates of that app in `developer.apple.com` and do the app updations

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know currently there is no way `Y` can only see the corresponding certificate of that particular app in apple developer portal.

Let say for example, `Y` is able to see the certificate but still `Y` needs the key used to generate the certificate in order to sign the ipa during the upload process. So, you have to export the `.p12`, download the provisioning profile and send it to `Y` in order to proceed to the app upload. Alternatively regenerate the resources on the corresponding account if possible.